# Submit button no function when is clicked

Tags: jquery, html

I have issued about submit button no function when is clicked.Anyone can help me to check which part I get wrong. Thanks.

```
          <!-- contact form -->
            <div class="col-lg-7 contact-right mt-lg-0 mt-5">

                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-lg-6 form-group pr-lg-2">
                            <input id="name" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Name" required="">
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-lg-6 form-group pl-lg-2">
                            <input id="email" type="email" class="form-control"  placeholder="Email" required="">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <input id="phone" type="text" class="form-control"  placeholder="Phone" required="">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <textarea id="message" class="form-control" placeholder="Message" required=""></textarea>
                    </div>
                    <button type="button" onclick="submit();" class="btn submit-contact-main ml-auto">Submit ok</button>

            </div>
            <!-- contact form -->
```

`script function`

```
        <script>
 function submit() {
   //alert("Hello! I am an alert box!!");
var name = $('#name').val();
var email = $('#email').val();
var phone = $('#phone').val();
var message = $('#message').val();
if (name == '' || email == ''|| phone == ''){
    alert("Please insert Full Name , Email and phone!");
}else{
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '?f=send_email',
        data: {
            name: name,
            email: email,
            phone: phone,
            message: message
        },
        success: function (data) {
        if(data=='1'){
            alert("Send Successfull. We will reply you soon.");
            location.reload();
            }else{
            alert("Error while processing data, please try again.");
            }
        }
    });
}
   }
</script>
```

I have using `alert("Hello! I am an alert box!!");` to test submit button, it can be worked and will popup the message. But until this coding `if (name == '' || email == ''|| phone == ''){alert("Please insert Full Name , Email and phone!");}`, it doesn't work and no popup the message. Hope anyone can help me find the problem. Thanks.

Comment: Can you check devtools and go to console tab?
Ctrl + Shift + i then go to console tab and check for errors.

Comment: Make sure you have included jquery before your script block.

Comment: Your code works fine  https://jsfiddle.net/b6xkg4yq/  as above, ensure jquery is loaded and check for errors in the console.  Don't use `alert()` for debugging, use `debugger` and the browser tools or `console.log(...)`.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] that **demonstrates** the problem.

Comment: Also, add as the first line of submit() the following: `console.log($("#name").length, $("#email").length, $("#phone").length);` - if any of these are not `1` then your code won't work as expected as you have duplicate IDs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
function submit() {
  //alert("Hello! I am an alert box!!");
  var name = $('#name').val();
  var email = $('#email').val();
  var phone = $('#phone').val();
  var message = $('#message').val();
  if (name == '' || email == '' || phone == '') {
    alert("Please insert Full Name , Email and phone!");
  } else {
    $.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      url: '?f=send_email',
      data: {
        name: name,
        email: email,
        phone: phone,
        message: message
      },
      success: function(data) {
        if (data == '1') {
          alert("Send Successfull. We will reply you soon.");
          location.reload();
        } else {
          alert("Error while processing data, please try again.");
        }
      }
    });
  }
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery.js">
</script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js">
</script>

<div class="col-lg-7 contact-right mt-lg-0 mt-5">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-6 form-group pr-lg-2">
      <input id="name" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Name" required="">
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-6 form-group pl-lg-2">
      <input id="email" type="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Email" required="">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <input id="phone" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Phone" required="">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <textarea id="message" class="form-control" placeholder="Message" required=""></textarea>
  </div>
  <button type="button" onclick="submit();" class="btn submit-contact-main ml-auto">Submit ok</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Nothing is wrong with your syntax. Double check your return value if it is returning "1". The values in the elements are submitting well to the same page.

The error must be in your sendEmail function.

Answer (score 0):

Just tried your code in a codepen, and had the exactly issue you're stating. But after i added jQuery import before the actual script, it worked out perfectly fine.

Remember to include the jQuery library somewhere in your code, it can be loaded from a CDN like this:

```
<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-CSXorXvZcTkaix6Yvo6HppcZGetbYMGWSFlBw8HfCJo="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Just include it anywhere before your script, and it should start working.

Comment: So you had "exactly" the same error message that $ is not defined that OP has not confirmed/denied they got?

Comment: I confirmed that nothing actually happened because of the jQuery library wasn't loaded, and worked perfectly after importing it.

Answer (score 0):

Possibly you have name/email/phone have values 'null' or 'undefined';
To check values you can write something like this:

```
function submit() {
       //alert("Hello! I am an alert box!!");
    var name = $('#name').val();
    var email = $('#email').val();
    var phone = $('#phone').val();
    var message = $('#message').val();
    console.log(name);
    console.log(email );
    console.log(phone);
    if (name == '' || email == ''|| phone == ''){
        alert("Please insert Full Name , Email and phone!");
    }else{
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: '?f=send_email',
            data: {
                name: name,
                email: email,
                phone: phone,
                message: message
            },
            success: function (data) {
            if(data=='1'){
                alert("Send Successfull. We will reply you soon.");
                location.reload();
                }else{
                alert("Error while processing data, please try again.");
                }
            }
        });
    }
       }
```

And check values in developer console (F12, possibly)

Answer (score 0):

try the following code.i hope its helfull for you and others

```
<button type="button" onclick="my_button_click_handler">Click this button</button>
<script>
function my_button_click_handler()
{
alert('Button Clcked');
}
</script>
```

in your case,`onclick="submit();"` but you try this `onclick="submit"`

Answer (score 0):

on top of your script tag add this script tag

```
<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-CSXorXvZcTkaix6Yvo6HppcZGetbYMGWSFlBw8HfCJo="
  crossorigin="anonymous">
</script>
```

to include jquery